# forcebindip: couldn't find named adapter

Tags: networking, network-adapter

As explained on [ForceBindIP](https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip), it can also take the GUID of an interface if for example the IP address is dynamic. To find out the GUID of your interface, run regedit and browse to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces. Find the interface which has the dynamic address and then copy the key name. 
So did

```
ForceBindIP.exe -i {d40ec244-0162-4303-8852-11c613be5e41} "C:\TOOLS\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe"
```

but I got

> couldn't find named adapter

Answer (score 2):

the GUID has to be in upper case letter

does not work

```
   ForceBindIP.exe -i {d40ec244-0162-4303-8852-11c613be5e41} "C:\TOOLS\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe"
```

that DOES work

```
   ForceBindIP.exe -i {D40EC244-0162-4303-8852-11C613BE5E41} "C:\TOOLS\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe"
```